Using conditions in laravel accessors
To show application_status in result, I'm using DB::raw statement in my query.
DB::raw('
        CASE
            WHEN status = 0 THEN "Pending"
            WHEN status = 1 THEN "Approved"
            WHEN status = 2 THEN "Declined"
        END AS application_status'
                )

How can I convert or write this in accessor?
Is there any other way to write above in laravel way.
$leave_applications = LeaveApplication::select('leave_type','total_days',DB::raw(
                    '
        CASE
            WHEN status = 0 THEN "Pending"
            WHEN status = 1 THEN "Approved"
            WHEN status = 2 THEN "Declined"
        END AS application_status'
                )
            ))->where('employee_id', $employee_id)->get();

This is my full query.
I read the laravel documentation and search google for above, but did not found anything.
I found the solution which uses ternary operators. But what if we have more than 2 conditions?

Are those status names in a lookup table? ... if so, you can get those names through a relation instead of needing an accessor.

No. They are not in any tables.

In my opinion, in case you're not storing the status in the database you should store it in a constant or config variable. We wanna avoid at all cost having different application_status for a given ID and consistency is the key for a project.
class LeaveApplication extends Model
{

public const PENDING_STATUS_NAME = 'Pending';
public const APPROVED_STATUS_NAME = 'Approved';
public const DECLINED_STATUS_NAME = 'Declined';

protected $appends = ['application_status'];

public function getApplicationStatusAttribute()
{
    return match ($this->level) {
        0 => $this::PENDING_STATUS_NAME ,
        1 => $this::APPROVED_STATUS_NAME ,
        2 => $this::DECLINED_STATUS_NAME 
    };
}

With this you will achieve your dessired application_status in the model.
I hope I understood your issue correctly.

you can also create a generated column
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html
